# Auto block attack to mail serve Debian with postfix

Tags: debian, postfix

I'm having huge problem. I removed the domains but somebody is still running, now even more, scripts from many different ip addresses in order get in and use my server for spamming.

In /var/log/syslog i constantly see new lines coming up:

```
Apr  2 01:55:35 158115 named[10131]: client 24.92.226.226#2100: query (cache) 'www.domain.com/A/IN' denied
Apr  2 01:55:35 158115 named[10131]: client 24.92.226.226#2101: query (cache) 'www.domain.com/A/IN' denied
Apr  2 01:55:35 158115 named[10131]: client 24.92.226.228#2969: query (cache) 'www.domain.com/A/IN' denied
Apr  2 01:55:35 158115 named[10131]: client 24.92.226.229#2050: query (cache) 'www.domain.com/A/IN' denied
```

And i notices at least 20-50 different ip addresses.

Is there way to auto block those attempts?

For ssh i use fail2ban and it's ok but i don't know how to react to this....

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with your mail server, and the requests were already blocked.

Comment: Today, i had this in postqueue -p this: -- 65037 Kbytes in 9180 Requests
Emails from same domains and i discovered backdoor in joomla installation that "idiot" site owner installed. The mail attack was towards sending emails.

Comment: OK, well, if you have log entries related to your question, you should post those, instead of the irrelevant ones.

Comment: It was about 6Gb of logs that i erased immediately after i saw that. Unfortunately i didn't have time to download and analyze those :( But anyway, i'm actually looking for better way to ban those attempts that are visible in syslog not something else :( If some other info can help, tell me, i'll post.

Comment: If you erased all the relevant logs, then nobody can help you.

Comment: Ok, when you see syslog as i posted, what would be your first reaction. (imagine you have no much other logs)

Comment: I already gave you that reaction. It was my very first comment. Did you read it?

Comment: So, by your opinion this is fine situation. I should ignore those attempts and enjoy my life?

Comment: You chose to ignore them when you deleted the evidence

Comment: I'm sorry for asking, i believe you are Gods and never make mistakes. In fact, i wonder, why do you need this place for? Or it's simply much easier to say "there is no help"?

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes. We have only pointed out the consequences of your particular mistake.

Comment: I still believe that the world is not that stupid and i have no doubt that something can be done about this. Anyway, thank you for even considering the question, no meter what you replied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments, you don't have this logged anymore. Logs are useful! Without logs you can't do any kind of diagnostic, nor can you take preventative measures. Some services (like the fail2ban you mentioned) rely entirely on logs to do their job. You are advised to not delete logs again until you're confident you won't need them.

Your best option now is to wait for it to happen again. Set up something like OSSEC to watch your logs and email you when too many failures have been logged.

Comment: Well, that is one of possible answers too. Thnx.